# Joining values of columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I have a query that fetches the list of user IDs and their corresponding user names on a board but from another table also gets a column that has a value (a name) on the row corresponding to the user ID if said user has changed their name. Using an outer join I got the three nicely displayed as in the following example of a few of the results:

```
member_id    name             dname_current
1            Blablabla1       blablabla2
2            Bla4444          
3            RevZ             
5            Herpaderp42      
6            Lalalala         
7            Kaboom           
14           testtesttest21   Formula21
15           Alex             Ethan
16           Bob              Radio3
```

The SQL query to get the three columns is as follows:

```
SELECT
  data_members.member_id, 
  data_members.name,
  data_dnames_change.dname_current
FROM data_members LEFT OUTER JOIN data_dnames_change
    ON data_members.member_id = data_dnames_change.dname_member_id
GROUP BY data_members.member_id
```

Is there a way to display this so that it merges the values which exist in the 'dname_current' column of that other table into the 'name' column, replacing any value that's already in the corresponding row of that column?

Comment: Is your problem that a user could have changed their name multiple times, so you want to show each of their name changes on one line?

Comment: Nah, the left outer join happens to pick the most recent name change, I've already established that. I merely want to merge the results as shown together so that if there's a name change listed it'll show that instead of the original (login) name. I'll look into your below answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) returns the first non-null value, so you can do the following to prefer `dbname_current` over `data_members.name` unless it is NULL:

```
SELECT
  data_members.member_id, 
  COALESCE(data_dnames_change.dname_current, data_members.name) AS name
FROM data_members LEFT OUTER JOIN data_dnames_change
    ON data_members.member_id = data_dnames_change.dname_member_id
GROUP BY data_members.member_id
```

Should return:

```
member_id    name
1            blablabla2
2            Bla4444
3            RevZ
5            Herpaderp42
6            Lalalala
7            Kaboom
14           Formula21
15           Ethan
16           Radio3
```

Comment: When previewing this query (using DBKiss, a PHP tool to manage databases) I get the following error:

Error: Unknown column 'data_dnames_change.dbname_current' in 'field list' (1054)

Comment: @RevZ Because I misspelled your column as `dbname_current` instead of `dname_current`. Fixed above.